# Capybara find_link gives ambiguous match error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara

```
<ul>
    <% @topic.contents.each do |content| %>
      <li>
        <%= content.content %> <%= link_to "Edit", edit_content_path(content) %> <br><br>
      </li>
    <% end %>
</ul>
```

I need someway to test this using Capybara. I tried typing this in my test file:

```
 test "there is an edit link on the show page" do
    click_link "Enter"
    click_link "Ruby"
    assert find_link("Edit").first.visible?
 end
```

But it winds up giving me a message:

```
 1) Error:
VisitorFindContentTest#test_there_is_an_edit_link_on_the_show_page:
Capybara::Ambiguous: Ambiguous match, found 2 elements matching link "Edit"
    test/integration/visitor_find_content_test.rb:44:in `block in <class:VisitorFindContentTest>'
```

What else can I do? What can be done? Should I do something to make each of my edits link unique? OR is there a capybara test method just that looks for the first appearance of an edit link?

Answer (score 0):

Add an `:id` or a `:class` specific to the `content` as follows:

```
<%= content.content %> <%= link_to "Edit", edit_content_path(content), id: "content_#{content.id}" %> <br><br>
```

or

```
<%= content.content %> <span id: "content_#{content.id}"><%= link_to "Edit", edit_content_path(content) %></span> <br><br>
```

You can then use this id for clicking the link as follows (with the second option above):

```
content = Content.first # or some way of finding the required content object  
within("#content_#{content.id}") do
  click_link("Edit")
end
```